# How to update target table column value comparing than two source table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two SQL Server source tables. Each table that contains two columns, one is phoneno1 & ID and the other columns are phoneno2 & ID.

First source table has 30k rows and second source table has 1.8 million rows including 20k records out of 30k records from source table1.

I have 100 target tables and each table contains only one column - phoneno.

I need to compare these above two source tables with 100 target tables one by one and if any target tables phoneno values is matched with source tables phoneno1&2 values then I have to overwrite that source table ID column value in to target tables phoneno values.

If not matching then I need to insert that not matching values into one new table that contains two columns phoneno & ID.

How to do achieve in SQL Server?

Comment: Creating 20k tables one row each.. Really?

Comment: You should use **internationally understood** measures - thousands, millions, billions

Comment: Can you add some sample source tables and what you want the final table(s) to look like?  But my guess is your going to end up with some kind of loop (or cursor) and dynamic sql (as the table name is a variable).  Start by just doing one match, which will be the target table joined to both your source tables.  Add that SQL to your question as well.

Comment: You would start by combining the 100 target tables into a *single* table with two columns.  One would be the the phone number.  The second would be an identifier to identify the table.

Comment: Below are the examples of expected results.                   soure table 1 
phoneno1 ID
12345678 11
88888888 22
77777777 33
11123232 44
 
source table 2 
 
65368853 88
12345678 11
77777777 33
 
Target table 
phoneno 
12345678 
88888888 
77777777 
11111111 
 
Expected result:
Target table 
phoneno 
11 
22 
22 
33 
11111111 should be moved to one new table because this value is not available in both source tables.